# Update rows in SQL that retain the old value

Tags: sql

My table in SQL

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
  Person_id INT PRIMARYKEY
  Person_name NVARCHAR(250)
)
```

Data in table:

```
INSERT INTO Person VALUES(1,'Peter')
```

I want update row in SQL that retain the old value.

```
UPDATE Person SET Person_name = 'Mary' WHERE Person_id = 1
```

This command does not work. I want after update column Person_name is value 'Peter Mary'

Comment: Does not work how? Can you post the error message? And what DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to concatenate the literal value `Mary` with the value of the column `Person_name` using your RDBMS concatenation operator. But, you didn't specify what RDNMS you are using.

Here is the standard way:

```
UPDATE Person 
SET Person_name = Person_name || ' ' || 'Mary' 
WHERE Person_id = 1;
```

For SQL Server use the `+` operator like so:

```
UPDATE Person 
SET Person_name = Person_name + ' ' + 'Mary' 
WHERE Person_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 6):

Is it this you want to archieve?

Before the update:

```
ID | Person_name
---+---------------
1  | Peter
```

After the update:

```
ID | Person_name
---+---------------
1  | Peter Mary
```

If you're for example using MySQL, you could use this approach:

```
UPDATE Person 
SET Person_name = CONCAT(Person_name, ' ', 'Mary') 
WHERE Person_id = 1
```

Just [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) a blank and the new value to the current value.

Please don't forget to add the RDBMS you're using. Other RDBMS might have different syntaxes and possibilities.